# Solving a $2^{nd}$ order BVP with unknown continuious coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

> Let $q, f \in C[0, 1]$ with $f < 0$ on $[0, 1]$. We need to find solution $y: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ to the BVP $$y'' + q y' = f$$ with $y(0) = y(1) = 0$ and to show $y'(0) > 0$ and $y'(1) < 0$.

My idea is to let $x = y'$ and re-write the ODE into 
$$x'= -qx + f$$
Using the general solution for $1^{st}$ order ODE, we have $$x = \frac{1}{e^{\int q(t) \mathrm{d}t}}\left(\int e^{\int q(t) \mathrm{d}t}f(t) \mathrm{d}t + c_1\right)$$ for some $c_1 \in \mathbb{R}$

Integrate again, we get $$y = \int \frac{1}{e^{\int q(t) \mathrm{d}t}}\left(\int e^{\int q(t) \mathrm{d}t}f(t) \mathrm{d}t + c_1\right) \mathrm{d}t + c_2$$ for some $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$

I don't how to proceed from here. How am I suppose to plug in the boundary conditions and to show the inequalities? Thank you.

Comment: $y(0) = 0$ and $y(0) > 0$?

Comment: @Mattos fixed!!

Comment: you can determine the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ by using BCs: $y(0)=y(1)=0$. It may be helpful to write $\int_0^x$ instead $\int$.

Comment: @daulomb What is "BCs"?

Comment: $y(0)=y(1)=0$ are the boundary conditions and do not confuse  $x$  as I mentioned with your $x$ in the substitution case.

Comment: Also the problem is not an  intial-value problem(IVP) it is a boundary value problem and there is millions condition on $f$ and $y$ :) I dont understand where they are required to find $y$.

Comment: @daulomb I haven't learnt about BVP before. I have only learnt about IVP. Btw, I think we have $c_2 = 0$ after replacing $\int$ by $\int_0^t$.

Comment: But $y(0)=y(1)=0  $ are boundary conditions, so you should check the problem once again. However you can still find $c_1$ and $c_2$ by using these two conditions. They will be integral of something from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @daulomb Ah, I understand now. My university changed the syllabus so it is not taught anymore. It is in the last chapter of my book. Thanks for your help!

Comment: so what is main problem?

Comment: @daulomb I don't understand. What do you mean by "main problem"? We would like to find solutions to the BVP and to show they satisfies the two inequalities.

Comment: you told that your university changed syllabus this means that your problem is an IVP. Ohh I get it okey

Comment: @daulomb No, I think you are right. The problem is a BVP. I am doing old exercise from my university to prepare for exam.

Comment: @Alex Vong: I posted what I've done for this problem. May be you want to take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the equation by the function $e^{\int_0^tq(s)ds}$ (integration factor) to
get $$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(y'e^{\int_0^tq(s)ds}\bigg)=f(t)e^{\int_0^tq(s)ds}.$$ Integrate both sides w.r.t. to $t$ we get
$$y'e^{\int_0^tq(s)ds}=\int_0^tf(u)e^{\int_0^uq(s)du}+c_1,$$ 
and from which we have
$$y'=e^{-\int_0^tq(s)ds}\int_0^tf(u)e^{\int_0^uq(s)ds}du+c_1e^{-\int_0^tq(s)ds}.\quad (1)$$

Integrating once more we find
$$y=\int_0^t\bigg[\bigg(e^{-\int_0^r q(s)ds}\int_0^rf(u)e^{\int_0^uq(s)}du\bigg)+c_1e^{-\int_0^r q(s)ds}\bigg]dr+c_2.$$ Since $y(0)=0$, $c_2=0$ and hence we have
$$y=\int_0^t\bigg[\bigg(e^{-\int_0^rq(s)ds}\int_0^rf(u)e^{\int_0^uq(s)}du\bigg)+c_1\displaystyle e^{-\int_0^r q(s)ds}\bigg]dr.\qquad (2)$$(This is the solution with $c_1$ given below). Also $y(1)=0$ implies that 
$$c_1=-\bigg(\int_0^1\displaystyle e^{\int_0^r q(s)ds}dr\bigg)\int_0^1\bigg[\int_0^r\bigg(e^{-\int_0^rq(s)ds}\int_0^rf(u)e^{\int_0^uq(s)}du\bigg)\bigg]dr,$$ which is a positive number since $f<0$. Substituting this into (1) we see that $y'(0)=c_1>0.$ A$$c_1=-\bigg(\int_0^1\displaystyle e^{\int_0^r q(s)ds}dr\bigg)\int_0^1\bigg[\int_0^r\bigg(e^{-\int_0^rq(s)ds}\int_0^rf(u)e^{\int_0^uq(s)}du\bigg)\bigg]dr,$$ which is a positive number since $f<0$. Substituting this into (1) we see that $y'(0)=c_1>0$. However I couldn't see why $y'(1)$ should be positive. It is not easy to deduce it from (1) directly. In this case I can only say that since $y'(t)$ is continuous and $y'(0)>0$ (means it increases as $t$ increases to $1$, but since $y(1)=0$ after some $t$ it starts to decreasing till to $1$, so $y'(1)<0$.(This could also be concluded if we know that the graph is concave,i.e., $y^{''}<0$.)(requires a combursome calculation). May be some doyens of the forum make contribution to clarify this point for me too.